# how to read a nand?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

There is a NAND Flash drive embedded into the motherboard I am using. Linux by default does not read NAND Flash, how can I modify my system to allow me to read the NAND flash drive like any other media (e.g. `/dev/sda*`)? 
Do I need to recompile the kernel myself? Or are there packages I can install (Ubuntu)?

Comment: Are you talking about the XBox NAND perhaps?

Comment: hopefully I have explained it better now

Comment: http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/nand.html